# Getting data from System.Collections.ObjectModel

Tags: c#

I have piece of code

```
object Items = (object)js.ExecuteScript("return angular.element(document.getElementById('bank-list')).scope().items");
```

If I try to use `Console.WriteLine(Items);`

It outputs`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection1[System.Object]`

My question is: **How I could get the data from the object?**

Data which should be in the `Items` variable is something like:

`[{"index": 383, "id": 12163, "count": 1676, "formattedCount": 1676}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var items = js.ExecuteScript("return angular.element(document.getElementById('bank-list')).scope().items") as ReadOnlyCollection<object>;
if(items != null)
{
    foreach (obj obj in items)
    {
        Dictionary<string,object> dict = obj as Dictionary<string, object>;
        if (dict != null)
        {
             foreach(var val in dict.Values)
                 Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I seem to get an error: `Additional information: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'id'`

Comment: Thanks again, this printed out everything.

Comment: Thanks for the help, if I may ask how could I print out only exact key? Example `id`?

Comment: Iterate over dict.Keys the same way as I did with dict.Values.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir.